# Problems of Controller in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I  am new to Angular Js and i have just done basic tags of angularjs and when i started controller part i understood the concept but was unable to fetch data input by user..Please guide me so that i can take one step further in AngularJS

Thanks in Advance!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div ng-app="nehaApp" ng-controller="Mayank">
Name : <input type="text" ng-model="Firstname">
Friends : <input type="text" ng-model="Friendname">

 {{  Firstname  + "  "  +  Friendname}} 

</div>

<script>

var appname = angular.module('nehaApp',[]);

appname.controller('Mayank',function($scope)
{
   $scope.Firstname = "Neha"; 
   $scope.Friendname = "Mayank";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to seperate the values like so: `{{  Firstname }} {{ Friendname }}` The + you have in there will actually try and evaluate whatever you have in there

Comment: `{{ Firstname + " " + Friendname}}` works and does output `Neha Mayank` and updates as expected when `input` are updated. So not sure what the question is here... Here's a working plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/LX8VpO5i7zVzovovc8Oo

Answer (score 2):

Ronnie comments says, you can see in my form example >>> https://plnkr.co/edit/n5qyRJ

Change your code:

```
{{  Firstname  + "  "  +  Friendname}}
```

By this:

```
{{Firstname}} {{Friendname}}
```

Seeya!
Jesus

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the following line of code in you HTML.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
```

This will import the angular library into your page.

This library is what allows you to have the angular directives,modules and controllers in your code.

Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Paras

Comment: Actually i have written that script was problem in copy paste sorry :)